# Custom annotation usage

Tags: java, annotations

I would like to define a custom annotation and use it with an Inject annotation in below manner. How to access the annotation value inside injected bean ?

Annotation Definition,

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface CustomAnnotation{
    String name();
}
```

Access annotation properties inside a bean,

```
@Component
public class Processor {
    Would like to know the value "abc" in constructor/post-constructor. How to access name method here ?
}
```

Test Usage (The value "abc" is used to load respective configuration and make the bean behave appropriately),

```
@Inject
@CustomAnnotation("abc")
Processor myProcessor;

public void test()
{
    myProcessor.process(); // myProcessor will behave based on value "abc"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the link for `@CustomAnnotation` :-

http://www.javatechblog.com/java/how-to-create-custom-annotation-in-java/

https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/